# How to make an HTTP request on page load in Angular (works with a button)

Tags: json, angular, http

I am trying to make an HTTP request to an API when my page loads and have the text of the response display on the screen. I am using Angular framework.

I currently have it working as I desire when you press a button. I want the exact functionality I have with the button, but for it to happen automatically on page load.

```
//TypeScript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {



posts: Observable<String[]>;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

  }

 public getPosts() {

  this.posts = this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

  }


ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
HTML
<button (click) = "getPosts()">GetPosts</button>

<div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
  Name
  {{post | json}}

</div>
```

This gives me a page with a button. When I press the button I get the information from the API. I want the API to give me the information right away when the page is loaded.

Comment: you can just move that into ngOnInit

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. I had tried writing getPosts(); in my ngOnInit, but your comment helped me realize I can just put the whole call of  
this.posts = this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'); 
into ngOnInit. Thank you! 

Now I just need to parse it so that I can display individual elements of that output rather than the whole thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Invoke the method on ngOnInit

```
    ngOnInit() {
           this.getPosts()
      }
```

or You can do like below also

```
    export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Observable<String[]> = this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

      constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

      }
    }
```

Comment: wow I am dumb. I tried this exact solution of putting getPosts() into ngOnInit...
I forgot to put this. before it. Sigh. 

Thanks a bunch! This is exactly what I needed. 

Would you happen to know how I am able to get a specific item out of the API strings? I want it to display just the ID number for example.

Comment: @skellyton3 you are welcome , if you want only id from each object in an array , you can use pluck operator for that.something like this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(pluck('id'))

Comment: Awesome! I was actually able to figure out exactly what I need. In my HTML I can just do {{post.id | json }} rather than {{post | json}}. Things are really coming together now. I think your method is probably a more proper way to do it though so that is good to know. Thank you so much for your help!